# Canvas animation flickering under Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, canvas, html5-canvas

No matter what I do, I can't get a fluent canvas animation under Firefox. I even set up a simple test code which does absolutely nothing except calling empty draw function every 1/40 s and it's still flickering.

```
var t = 0;
function draw(time)
{
  console.log(Math.round(time - t));
  t = time;
}

setInterval(function(){ requestAnimationFrame(draw); }, 25);
```

Delay between frames under Firefox sometimes jumps to over 150 ms which is easily noticable by human eye. Same thing happens when using simple `setInterval` to call `draw()`, without the `requestAnimationFrame`. It runs perfectly under Chrome and Opera.

I've also tried getting rid of `setInterval`, results are the same:

```
var t = 0;
function draw(time)
{
  requestAnimationFrame(draw);
  console.log(Math.round(time - t));
  t = time;
}
draw();
```

Is it a known issue? Is there any way to work around it?

Comment: the console.log in firefox might just be more expensive. try logging the amount of frames per second instead.

Comment: Is your app in a background-tap or somthing like that? Most browsers turn the drawing-frequence down if the canvas is not visible.

Comment: btw: setIntervall combined with requestAnimationFrame is a little strange. Just use requestAnimationFrame, otherwise you will have two simultanious timer, I dont know how browser react to that.

Comment: 1) Use fillText on the canvas to show frame time. Console.log is very slow. 2) Use only requestAnimationFrame.

Comment: He's not using both... Answers about logging won't help either. You should look into css. For instance the canvas will automatically refresh every time with width or height is changed, maybe an animation is running? Maybe there is some force draw css var for firefox?

If not that then hardware settings, graphics cards updates, firefox settings, firefox versions. Anything could cause this, maybe someone has listed a bug report for your firefox version somewhere. What other browsers work for sure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the current implementation of `requestAnimationFrame` under Firefox is terrible and fails to provide smooth animation when called from timers or network events (even those which are repeated at constant interval).

This makes it hard to redraw canvas when state is updated over websocket connection. The only way I could get smooth animation was calling `requestAnimationFrame` immediately:

```
(function draw()
{
   requestAnimationFrame(draw);
   // do something
})();
```

When using this method, it's quite often a good idea to implement some kind of frame interpolation, as `draw()` calls won't be synchronized with network events.